# Express backend deployment failed on Elastic Beanstalk with codepipeline

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy this boilerplate express application to aws elastic beanstalk
`https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-boilerplate`

What I did:

- I created an application on Elastic Beanstalk with default sample code. It's working
- Added codepipeline for that application
- The code is loading from the source
- Deployment failed.

I haven't deployed an express application directly with this format. So, a proper guideline would really help.

This boilerplate code runs via some predefined commands ( you can see the documentation on github, I'm not using the docker, only node environment)

So my question is, I haven't put any commands like yarn build yarn dev on any configuration. Is it not working because of that? If so, where and do I edit those.

Please share a complete guide. That would be the best solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZdP4gbMtaE) link?